# How to set screen orientation from code in a viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

So I have an implemented viewpager in my application, and I would like to set the screen orientation PORTRAIT on every page, except one, that should be using BOTH. Now im using this code, but in this case every page using BOTH orientation.

In Mainfest:

```
<activity android:name=".ViewPagerActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

In the fragment:

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

Comment: where exactly you call this line? `getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);` You do it in wrong place, I think when you init the viewpager (on activity start)

Comment: @VladMatvienko In the targeted fragment.

Comment: That's wrong. Since View pager works not like you think it does. You should call it on viewPager page change to desired index

Comment: @VladMatvienko If i call it in my viewpager, how  do I locate my target fragment?

Comment: you don't need to locate a fragment, you should only know the position of the fragment in the viewpager. So it looks like this (pseudocode) : `onPageSeleted(int position) { if(position == verticalOrientationFragmentPosition) {<set vertical orientation>} else {set sensor orientation}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [setUserVisibleHint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean))

in your `ViewPager` fragments

From Documentation:

> Set a hint to the system about whether this fragment's UI is currently
>   visible to the user. This hint defaults to true and is persistent
>   across fragment instance state save and restore.

so in your particular fragment override this method and apply the Orientation change.

For example:

```
 @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser) {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if(activity != null) activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
    }
}
```